# Java Creating a Huffman Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, huffman-code

I'm currently in the process of creating a Huffman Tree using a Priority Queue.
I understand the concept of how the Huffman Tree works, however while implementing it I have been finding it difficult to produce the code.

Currently I have this:

```
public void CreateHuffmanTree(String[] symbols, int[] frequencies)
  {
      PriorityQueue PQ = new PriorityQueue();
      for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++)
      {
          BSTNode temp = new BSTNode(symbols[i]);         
          PQ.AddItem(temp, frequencies[i]);            
      }         
      do
      {
          BSTNode hold = new BSTNode();
          int intHold = (PQ.QueueArray[0].priority + PQ.QueueArray[1].priority);
          hold.data = Integer.toString(intHold);

          hold.leftChild =  new BSTNode(PQ.GetNextItem().toString());
          hold.rightChild =  new BSTNode(PQ.GetNextItem().toString());         

          PQ.AddItem(hold, intHold);

      } while (PQ.queueSize > 1);   

     System.out.println(PQ.GetQueueSize());
  }
```

However when I test the code, it produces this:
  [image]

My PQ.GetNextItem() returns an object with the data for the Node, in my testing case it is letters such as "A" or "G" etc. So I used .toString() to convert it to a string to then create a new BSTNode.

Could anyone shed some light as to why my BST isn't forming the way it should?

Comment: Are you using a custom implementation of PriorityQueue? PQ.AddItem(temp, frequencies[i]) isn't a standard function in the library.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information.  We can't see all the relevant code, and you're not clear on exactly what the problem is, other than "it's not forming the way it should".  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Thats correct - I've got my own implementation. Would it be useful if I posted my Priority Queue implementation?

Comment: Yes it would. But i think once you do PQ.GetNextItem() if you do another period it will expose the properties of the PQ and then do .toString() on that. Or Override the toString method in your priority queue class and print it that way. Post the PQ implementation it should help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure (and I don't have enough rep to comment, sadly) without seeing the code you're using, but I have a theory:

Are you using your own `PriorityQueue`?  If so, I think you may have forgotten to return the contents of a node, and rather returned a node - this would explain why `PQ.getNextItem().toString()` is returning "ads2.PQNode@1cfe4b2", as it means you're getting back an `ads2.PQNode` object, which I don't think is your intended behavior.